# Prove that $\Phi(x,y)=\pi(x)-\pi(y)+1$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

> Define, $\displaystyle \Phi(x,y)=\sum_{n\le x, \substack\\ p|n\implies p>y }1$. Prove that if $\sqrt x <y\le x$ then, $\Phi(x,y)=\pi(x)-\pi(y)+1$, where $\pi(x)$ denotes the number of primes less or equal to $x$.

I've deduced that $\displaystyle \Phi(x,y)=1+\sum_{y<p\le x}\Phi(x/p,p)$. Also we have, $\pi(x)-\pi(y)\le \Phi(x,y)$. From these two how to proceed further ?

Comment: I don't understand the notation in the definition of $\Phi$. You seem to have two dummy variables $n,p$, so is this essentially a sum over pairs $(n,p)$ with constraints depending on $(x,y)$? Or is it supposed to be a single sum, with two constraints on the summation variable $n$, so the latter one has a universal quantifier over primes $p$?

Comment: @ian $p$ is meant to be a prime, and there's an implicit 'for all $p$' implied by the arrow - the constraint on the sum is 'any prime factors of $n$ are $\gt y$'.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes, after looking at it for a little bit longer I arrived at that possibility...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually looking in somewhat the wrong direction — rather, consider just breaking down the definition itself: for a number $n$ to "contribute to" $\Phi(x,y)$, by definition, it has to have all of its prime factors $\gt y$. Now, what can you say about composite numbers with all of their prime factors $\gt \sqrt{x}$?

Comment: There are no prime factor of $x$ greater than $\sqrt x$

Comment: As $p>\sqrt x$ so $p|n$ implies $n=p$. Am I right?

Comment: @Topo The quantifier matters: the point is that if *all* prime factors of $n$ exceed $\sqrt{n}$, then $n$ is prime. A composite number $n$ can easily have a prime factor exceeding $\sqrt{n}$ but then it will have a different prime factor less than $\sqrt{n}$. ($6$ is the minimal example here.)

Comment: Yeah ....Got it..